# Heroku Websockets with Java ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Tags: java, heroku, java-server, java-websocket

I am writing a small game server using Java.

I use [TooTallNate-Java-Websockets](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) library to create my websocket server.
Everything works when I run my server on localhost , I can connect to it from everywhere.However when I submit my app to Heroku , every time I try to establish a socket connection I get an error **ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)**.

Worth to mention , that when I am running my app with foreman which is supposed to emulate heroku environment , everything works as it should.

As a port for my websocket server I tried to use **8080** and many others in range between **5000** to **8000**.

I can only guess what is going on there on heroku , as logs contain only basic info of http requests.

Please help , I am close to give up :(

**EDIT**

Here is what I have in my Proc file:

```
web: ./build/install/my-app/bin/my-app
```

**UPDATE**
Created a simple abstraction app to showcase the problem:
(Tested in foreman of course , and it works in local environment)

1. My html/js tester : [Testerpage](http://pastie.org/10222341)
2. My Main java Jetty server : [Java Main](http://pastie.org/10222342)
3. Console error message : 
   `WebSocket connection to 'wss://test-websocket-yan.herokuapp.com:39773/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: Are you binding your app the the `$PORT` env var on Heroku? You say you are trying ports between 5000 and 8000. Is that on Heroku?

Comment: What do you mean by binding the  $PORT env var , in the Proc file ? No. Should I ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am answering my own question to share how I've managed to connect to Java websocket server on Heroku.

1. Create your web socket server using Java , the implementation is up to you , you can use javax or Jetty websockets or [TooTallNate-Java-Websockets](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) , I've used Jetty. Here is my [implementation](http://pastie.org/10230842)  . I have followed [this](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples) example.
2. When connecting to your web socket on heroku use the following scheme **ws:// + yourHerokuAppAdress + yourSocketEndpoint** . The endpoint is the relative adress that your websocket is listening on , in my case it is **"/socket"** . No Need to specify port !

Comment: Hey, I'm deploying my java websocket app on heroku. Everything is fine but I cannot connect to it using java client (which works if deployed on localhost) it gives `javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error`

Comment: I used `ws://localhost:8080/Dashboard/hello` while on local host and `ws://host_name/Dashboard/hello`

Answer (score 4):

You must use the port that Heroku sets as the `$PORT` env var:

> On Heroku, apps are completely self-contained and do not rely on runtime injection of a webserver into the execution environment to create a web-facing service. Each web process simply binds to a port, and listens for requests coming in on that port. The port to bind to is assigned by Heroku as the PORT environment variable.

For more see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers

Comment: Thanks , I'll try that . But does it mean I cannot use any other port ? What if I need 3 different ports to listen on ?

Comment: Heroku supports one port per application process. Instead of using a different port for the WS, you will need to use a different route in your app. There are third-party [tools for exposing auxiliary ports](http://jkutner.github.io/2015/05/19/heroku-remote-debug-java.html) but that might not be suited to this case.

Comment: I have just tested with the local $PORT environment variable.Didn't make any difference :( See please my update in a question , I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: Ok , I've made it ! The interesting part is I didn't have to add any port to my wss connection ! :) It is like so now : "wss://test-websocket-again.herokuapp.com/events/" :)

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to have `REDIS_URL` set. It was in `REDISCLOUD_URL` in my case.